# sending Action Mailer emails with Sidekiq and without Active Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

i'm interested in running a rails app with sidekiq, and without active job. i find that if active job is there, people get confused if they should use active job apis or sidekiqs, and i want to use sidekiq's apis exclusively for performance reasons.

does current versions of sidekiq (i.e. version 7) support active mailer without active job's `deliver_later`? i think the historical way to do this was through "delayed extensions" but i see now this has been removed in sidekiq 7:

> Delayed extensions provide a very easy and simple way to make method calls asynchronous. By default, all class methods and ActionMailer deliveries can be performed asynchronously.
> **They were disabled in Sidekiq 5 and removed in Sidekiq 7.**

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions

so given that, is there a recommended way to use action mailer with sidekiq and without active job these days?

Comment: Delayed extensions is extracted into a gem https://github.com/gemhome/sidekiq-delay_extensions did you try that?

Comment: @tejasbubane thanks, that seems like the best option available that doesn't use active job